# Share extension custom UI. Button has not got image

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-share-extension, ios-extensions

I am using share extension with custom UI, So I configured my view controllers in storyboards, and add image (and tried add background image) to the button. So in storyboard I see that image. But when I run extension I don't see image on the button.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is because seems I don't add my images to the new target. So if you create a new target, and extension it's our new target we should be sure that all needed resources like images, strings are added to it.

So just use target membership to checkmark needed files or add it via xcode project "Build Phases" tab.

So it's also connected to other classes you want to use. Sometimes can be a pain to add all of them because some classes import other classes and etc.